# System.NotSupportedException Xamarin Forms ListView Render

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I've received this error in Xamarin Forms:
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter from native handle 0xa7c0003d (key_handle 0xb10823e0).

This is xaml of my Page

```
    <ListView  x:Name="outerListview" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding articoliList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell x:Name="outerListviewCell">
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Grid
                                Margin="8,0,0,0"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    FontSize="Medium"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                    Text="{Binding Articolo.ItemCode}"/>
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    FontSize="Small"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                    Text="{Binding Articolo.ItemName}"/>
                                <ListView 
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    x:Name ="innerListview" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Bin}"
                                    HasUnevenRows="True">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell x:Name="InnerListviewCell">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Label
                                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                                        FontSize="Small"
                                                        TextColor="Black"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                                        Text="{Binding BinCode}"/>
                                                    <Label
                                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                                        FontSize="Small"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                                        Text="{Binding OnHandQty,StringFormat='Quantità:{0}'}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

articolist is ObservableCollection

```
public class Rows{
   public Articolo Articolo{get;set;}
public List<Bin> Bin{get;set;}
}
```

I think the problem is due to the fact that in some cases my list consists of 100 elements (then code, description and an additional ListView consisting of 2 labels per cell) and is too heavy for the app, am I wrong?
Or the fact that you can not graft a ListView in a ListView?

Comment: Not sure what causes this, but a `ListView` in a `ListView` is a bad idea no matter what.

Comment: Are there any controls or components to display the elements of the List <Bin>?

Comment: As documented in this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39451 it seems the nested `ListView` _does_ cause the crash. Of course I don't know what your requirements are or what you're trying to build. But I would advise finding another way to visualize it.